# Validate time in format as" hh:mm:ss am/pm " in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone tell me how  to validate time (which is an html input element) in the format as hh:mm:ss AM/PM in javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably better regexes out there but lets do something basic.

Get the input and attach an event on blur (will not explain how to do this; search for 'attach event to dom element in javascript' or something alike)

In that even you can do something like this:

```
if(/(?:[0-1]?[0-9]|[2][1-4]):[0-5]?[0-9]:[0-5]?[0-9]\s?(?:am|pm)?/.test(this.value)) {
    // Validates
} else {
    // Something is wrong
}
```

For better regexes to test time formats, or other formats, search for 'validate time regex javascript' or something similar (there are tons out there).

This particular regex validates time, you can play arround with it here if you want:

http://rubular.com/r/cYs1n3UuKO

Bear in mind that ruby and javascript regexes do differ slightly, but for something as simple as this you can use rubular which has a good interface for easy testing.

Comment: can you tell me how to make am/pm case insensitive

Comment: Thats fairly simple, I showed how to use the regex as a literal object here, but if you construct it using the [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object you can add flags like case-insensitivity. `var regex = RegExp('(?:[0-1]?[0-9]|[2][1-4]):[0-5]?[0-9]:[0-5]?[0-9]\s?(?:am|pm)?', 'i')` and then just `regex.test(this.value)`

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way is probably to use [globalize.js](https://github.com/jquery/globalize), which lets you test simply for

```
Globalize.parseDate(data, 'T')
```

for not being null, e.g. `if(Globalize.parseDate(data, 'T')) ...`. This particular variant requires the exact format you exemplified, with seconds and am/pm indicator always included, though case-insensitively for the am or pm designator. You can use other formats instead of `T` to specify different parsing.

An additional beauty of this approach is that this piece of your code will be globalization-ready. Just setting a variable identifying the locale, you can make the code parse by the rules of different languages (for “long time” notations, in this case). Check out some [code samples](http://www.bytelevelbooks.com/books/global_javascript.html) that illustrate the possibilities.

Comment: thanks for your response ,but I already solve the issue using regular expressions,anyways I would definitely research on the above class,ty